# How to localize View with a localizationService in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, localization, ninject

I am developing an application which is using ASP.NET MVC3 for the front end which talks to service layer via interfaces.  All of the interfaces/services are injected into the controllers via ninject and constructor injection.

I would like to funnel all localization through a location service which is provided by ninject.

Easy enough on the controller side, I have added a Localize function in the controller base class and added the ILocalizeService to the constructor, and voila, done. Anytime I need to localize a string, I can just call the localize function which in turns calls the service.

Now I am trying to figure out a clean way to do this on the View side. I have a base View class which exposes a Localize function like in the controller so I can pass any static text on the view, but I can't figure out a clean way to get an instance of my localization service. I have read numerous posts saying that DI into a view is bad practice, but in this case I think the base view is the cleanest place to centralize the localization of text in the view (of course, I would be open to any other option which doesn't require me passing my kernel around)

Any examples someone could point me to or advice on how to do this cleanly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ninject allows property injection into views. This is bad practice though. You should do as little as possible in the view.

I think the main problem lies in the fact that you are using a custom localization service instead of going one of the standard ways to use resource files or custom views per language. See [this excellent blog post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx)

Or is there any special reason for an own way to deal with localization?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually got some of my ideas from the i18n nuget package Scott references at the end of that post. The application I am working on has a web front end, along with an api which both talk through the service layer, and the API needs to be localized as well. Technically I could localize the view separately via resource files or view per language (Since that data is not ever accessed through the api), but I wanted to centralize all of my translations in one place in the service layer

Comment: I just figured out how to inject a service into a view via property injection. Is there a mechanism in Ninject/MVC that allows you to use constructor injection for a view, or is it just not possible with how views are created in the framework?